# Active Directory userPrincipleName is different from user logon name

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, userprincipal

I have an application where I need to login to AD, and then I have to get user's **distinguishedName**.

I am successfully able to login to AD using the provided logon name, but when I try to search user object in AD, The query returns nothing.

My query is (Here I am assuming logon name as userPrincipleName):

**userPrincipleName=user@sub.domain.com**

When I looked further into this I found that for this user we have -

**user logon name = user@sub.domain.com**
**userPrincipleName = user@domain.com**

As far as I know, **logon name should be same as userPrincipleName**.
Can someone tell me if such scenario is actually possible where these two attributes can be different ?

If it is possible then how can I get **distinguishedName** of user, using the logon name provided ?

Comment: in Active Directory, generally you use `sAMAccountName` attribute for identifying the user. That's what I've been using for many years..

Comment: @anacron, is the sAMAccountName unique across all the users ? How do I get the sAMAccountName from the user's logon name(should I directly use the part before @). I would also like to know if situation I have explained is possible (where logon name and userPrincipleName are different).

Comment: It's same across all users. You should filter for `sAMAccountName=login_name`. The `distinguishedName` is generally the full name of the user.

Comment: @anacron, I didn't understand what u mean by "It's same across all users"? My queries are as I mentioned earlier, how to I get sAMAccountName from login id ? I also would like to know if two users can have same sAMAccountName in AD ?

Comment: I meant, the `sAMAccountName` attribute exists for all users. Sorry for the ambiguity in my earlier comment. It contains the user ID for each user. This will be the login ID generally input by the users when they try to login.

Comment: @anacron, Thanks for the clarification. Could you please answer my other queries as well about the uniqueness of sAMAccountName across users and how to get it from logon id/UPN (should I directly use the part before @ as sAMAccountName) ? Thanks.

Comment: The user will provide his/her login ID and password while logging in, for example `jdoe` and `password`. You will then use this to look up the user's profile using `sAMAccountName=jdoe` and get the `distinguishedName`. Since `jdoe` will be a unique ID, the search result will be exactly 1 entry. Once you get the DN, use it to perform a bind with the `password` provided by the user. If the password matches, the "bind" will be successful, otherwise the bind fails and user is not allowed to login.

Comment: @anacron, Thanks. Right now I am taking login id in either UPN format or pre-windows 2000 format (user@domain OR domain\user). then I use this login id as security principle in java ldap along with password. And it works for me to get the LDAP context. Then I use LdapContext to run query to get user's DN. Do you think I can enhance my workflow as you suggested ? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Active Directory has many naming attributes:

**distinguishedName**: This is the full LDAP DN of the object, like cn=Joe Smith, ou=Users,dc=MyDomain,dc=com and this must be unique within the tree and is enforced, which is to say the cn=Joe Smith node has to be unique in the container: ou=Users,dc=MyDomain,dc=com

**sAMAccountName**: This is usually the short name of the user. Must be unique within the domain and is enforced.  Like geoffc or jsmith.

**User Principal Name**: This looks like an email address, and with Office 365 will be your email address. geoffc@mydomain.com This is supposed to be unique within your forest but uniqueness is not actually enforced, and via LDAP you can write even nonsense into this field. At the root of the domain you can define addition SPN (Service Provider Names? I think) that then show up in Active Directory Users and Computers as a possible domain extension to add to a user. However, even though ADUC shows it as a split attribute, a value and then a domain suffix, it is stored as a simple string.

**displayName**: This is usually Joe Smith, the name that is displayed for the user.

**mail**: The users actual email address, jsmith@mail.mydomain.com.  With Office365 this is the value that should be in UserPrincipalName as well.

So decide what you can ask the user for on login, then look for that appropriate attribute.  UPN, if not using Office 365 is actually the least reliable value to use.

Comment: Right now in our AD integration, we take user's login id (UPN/logon name) as input to use as security principle in LDAP. then we use the same login id as UPN to get the user object from AD. Should we change that behaviour ? Any suggestions ? is sAMAccountName better alternative ?